# Piezo vs Mems Accelerometer - Different Amplitudes

Tags: signal-processing, vibration

I am using a MPU 9250 (three axis accelerometer) with an ESP 8266 to perform vibration monitoring.

I am trying to compare vibration results between the Mems and a PCB ICP piezo accelerometer (model 352C33), but I am finding some divergences, such as max, min and rms acceleration amplitude.

Follow some images from the test performed on industrial machines:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCEf7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwa5i.png)

Note that I am getting +/-50% less amplitude with the Mems sensor, and I can't understand why...

Even when I perform simple test with sinusoidal signal, there are amplitude differences:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmAOU.png)

I already performed a test with the sensor stopped on the table, and it's delivering 0g in X and Y direction and 1g in the Z direction (vertical).
Do you have any idea of what can be my problem?

Comment: MPU9250 is a toy, I don't even see a accuracy or resonant frequency specification in its datasheet. I would much rather characterize these kind of devices as indicators instead of sensors. The PCB sensors are actually usable. Also try it with greater amplitude, it might be an offset error what you see instead of an error in the scale factor. Try somehow fixing them but-to-but and then violently shaking them with your hands. The waveforms should be each other's inverses.You can go from there. Also do an FFT and see the differences there. Resonant issues should be visible in the spectrum.

Comment: Ah, and also MOUNTING; Mounting is everything in vibration diagnostics. If you hadn't mounted one of them correctly you might very possibly have created a resonance or a dampening.

Comment: Thanks Cerike. What mems accelerometer would be feasible to make this comparison? Do have anything on mind?

Comment: The MPU datasheet has a noise of 300ug/raiz(Hz)...I don't know really well how I can "calculate" the MPU "error" based on its datasheet, but from the information listed on datasheet, the "error" would be micro g...which is very low compared to the amplitude I am measuring.